# Find a representation of the functions $f(x)=1-x$ and $g(x)=\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}(x)$ in terms of the exponential basis $\{e^{2\pi ixn}\}$

Tags: functional-analysis

Find a representation of the functions $f(x)=1-x$ and $g(x)=\chi_{(0,\frac{1}{2})}(x)$ in terms of the exponential basis $\{e^{2\pi ixn}\}$ of $L^2(0,1)$. Recall that the characteristic function $\chi_D$ of a subset $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined $\chi_{(D)}=1$ if $x \in D$ and $\chi_D(x)=0$ if $x \notin D$.

How would I do this? Can I just get instructions for $f$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exponential functions $\{ e_{n}(x)=e^{2\pi i n x}\}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$ form a complete orthonormal basis of $L^{2}[0,1]$. That means that the following always converges in $L^{2}[0,1]$ for all $f \in L^{2}[0,1]$:
$$
           f = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(f,e_{n})e_{n},
$$
where
$$
       (f,e_{n})=\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\overline{e_n(x)}\,dx=\int_{0}^{1}(1-x)e^{-2\pi inx}\,dx.
$$

Comment: So the representation is just the inner product? If so $\langle g,e_n \rangle=\int_0^\frac{1}{2} e^{-2\pi inx}\,dx$

Comment: @UsernameUnknown : That's right. The $\langle g,e_{n}\rangle$ terms are the coefficients of $e^{2\pi inx}$ in the expansion.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:*

You want to find the coefficients $c_n$ such that

$$f(x) = \sum_n c_n e^{2\pi i n x}$$

Since the basis vectors are orthogonal, normalize them and then use the inner product of $L^2(0,1)$

Comment: What are the basis vectors? I know that then I need to find the magnitude of the vectors and then the inner product is an intergral from 0 to 1.

Comment: The basis vectors are the functions $\{e^{2\pi ixn}\}$ (!)

Comment: Ok then I am confused with what to do. Can you explicitly show that needs to be done?